# Вопрос по DDD. Являются ли DTO частью доменного ядра?

Tags: архитектура, проектирование, ddd

В парадигме *Domain Driven Design*, говорят о том, что при разработке приложения отталкиваемся от проектирования доменного ядра, то есть, *доменных сущностей*, *агрегатов*, *доменных сервисов*, *репозиториев*.

**Вопрос**, являются ли *DTO* и классы превращатели в *доменные сущности* и обратно (*DTO->DomainEntities*, *DomainEntities->DTO*) частью доменного ядра или нет?

Задаю этот вопрос, потому что в обоих случаях встречаются непонятки.

**1)** Случай, что то, что связано с *DTO* не является частью доменного ядра. Непонятка: Чтобы *DTO* превратить в *Доменную сущность*, нужен *репозиторий*, т.к. *Доменная сущность* часто более информативная, чем *DTO*, ее нужно вытаскивать из *репозитория*. Значит логика превращения из *DTO* в *Доменную сущность* диктует логику доменного ядра, то есть, диктует какие методы должны быть в *репозитории*. Но доменное ядро должно быть независимо...

**2)** Случай, что *DTO* является частью *доменного ядра*. Не понятно то, что ведь логично, чтобы именно сборка с *DTO* стала общей и на сервер и на клиент. То есть хорошо, чтобы она была независимой от *доменного ядра*. Если расшаривать само доменное ядро, то на клиенте станут видны и *репозитории* и *доменные сервисы*, что ни к чему.

Возможно, у кого-то есть соображения или опыт в этом деле. Буду рад любым мыслям, советам :)

**EDIT:**
Вопрос, в принципе, о том, как реализовать *DDD* на практике. Правильно сказали, что термина *Доменного ядра* нет, а под ним я имел ввиду содержимое сборок *Domain Layer*-а, которое собственно содержит логическую сердцевину.

Comment: s/сущьност/сущност

Comment: в слове "сущность" мягкий знак есть только в самом конце

Answer (score 6):

> The purpose of software engineering is to control complexity, not to create it

Разбиение на сборки можно использовать для чего угодно. А можно - не использовать.

Любой сорсконтроль отлично смержит изменения от нескольких людей в одном проекте.

Идеологии DDD абсолютно все равно - в той же сборке лежат DTO, в отдельной, или их вообще нет (а вдруг не нужны!). DTO, DDD, идеологии и паттерны, механизмы разбиения на сборки, разделение на layers и tiers (клиент, сервер, база, UI) - это инструменты решения задач. Каждый из них решает свою, независимую проблему.

- DDD - это подход, решающий проблему выражения бизнес-логики в терминах вашего ЯП - классов и объектов - тем, что предлагает плясать прежде всего от домена. А не, скажем, от структуры базы данных.
- DTO - это паттерн, решающий проблему передачи данных (для удаленных вызовов, вне зависимости от того, что считается "удаленным вызовом" в конкретном контексте). Ему все равно, в рамках DDD вы его применяете, или у вас anemic модель, и вы просто на вызове свойств по ремоутингу экономите. Или у вас вообще нет удаленных вызовов (тогда у вас [Local DTO](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/LocalDTO.html)). DTO в [узком классическом смысле](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) используются именно для удаленных вызовов, и место им в SL (потому что только он занимается удаленными вызовами). Но общепринятый термин настолько уплыл в сторону еще-и-Local DTO, что с большой вероятностью вы увидите неймспейс BusinessLogic.DTO в каждом втором проекте - просто потому, что называть его LocalDTO в проекте, в котором нет RemoteDTO всем лень.
- Сборки - это единицы компиляции. Способ хранения кода на диске. И только. Им все равно, что в них хранится - классы руки мега-гуру DDD, или спагетти. Они не предназначены для чтения их людьми.
- Разбиение на клиент сервер (логическое или физическое, layers или tiers) - это просто способ разрезать код на куски, и изолировать ответственность каждого куска.
- Паттерн репозиторий не решает проблему вытаскивания чего-то откуда-то. Он решает проблему представления таблицы в базе в виде массива доменных объектов. Он прямо прилинкован к Data Mapping Layer. Как он в принципе может быть "независимым"?

Является DTO частью доменного ядра или не является - без разницы. Потому что из такого размытого по формулировке вопроса нельзя извлечь практическую пользу.

Более того, я уверен что устоявшегося термина "доменного ядра" нет. Есть понятие Core Domain - но это именно "основной домен". Встречается понятие "Ядро DDD" - но это "ядро методологии, ее основные составляющие". Вы сами себе ввели понятие "доменного ядра", включили в него то, что вам захотелось, придумали необоснованные ограничения, и пытаетесь на основе этого делать выводы. Так не получится.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Ознакомлюсь попозже и прокомментирую :)

Comment: Не совсем согласен, что все равно, где хранятся DTO. Мой вопрос касался скорее того, как применить DDD на практике, чтобы все было стройно. Хорошо, чтобы и разбиение на сборки логически отвечало DDD. Однозначно нельзя дать ответ на данный вопрос, но кажется сейчас уже есть какие-то устоявшиеся авторитетные мнения, что хорошо, а что плохо в данной концепции. Не во всем разбираюсь, но мне кажется, что лучше, чтобы DTO были отдельно от доменной логики, не в той же сборке.

Comment: @AndreyK. хотелось бы обоснования. разделение на сборки - это чисто физическое разделение. самому по себе рантайму абсолютно все равно, где объявлен класс. т.е. если DTO должны физически использоваться на машине, где не должно быть домена - их придется отделить (случай тру-дто). Если не должны - то опираться только на авторитетные *мнения* - недостаточно. Посмотрите, у меня много репутации и пачка желтых кружков - я достаточно авторитетен? :) Необоснованные мнения - опасны, потому что нельзя делать что-то, не понимая до конца зачем это что-то делается.

Comment: мне кажется, что если отделить DTO от Domain Layer, то это будет в большей степени отвечать концепции DDD, т.к. Domain Layer останется островом, где только логика, и транспортный уровень никак не будет примешиваться. Если логика - это одно, а транспорт вместе с дто - это другое, то хорошо и на сборки разные разделить. Тогда не будет соблазна в одном использовать другое. Вопрос, что наиболее эффективно в той или иной ситуации: для больших или маленьких проектов, когда надо расширяться или не надо; кому что надо...

Comment: @AndreyK. Об этом (и заодно о разнице между dto и local dto) и написано в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо за потраченное время! Почитал подробнее про LocalDto. Хорошая статья. Раньше не так внимательно прочитал. Все равно остаются вопросы. Может быть в будущем еще спрошу уточняющие моменты. Прошу прощения еще раз за нечетко сформулированный вопрос.

Answer (score 5):

Ссылка на [аналогичный вопрос на Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33895762/ddd-should-a-dto-assembler-be-a-part-of-domain-layer/33912568?noredirect=1#comment55588617_33912568)

**Устраивающий ответ:** *DTO* и *DtoAssemblers* **не** должны быть частью *Domain Layer* (или как я назвал это *доменным ядром*).

Концепция **DDD** говорит в основном о логике приложения и общения с заказчиком. Заказчик не должен ничего знать о технических подробностях, как *дто*.

Моя **ошибка** была в том, что на *DtoAssembler* накладывал обязанность формирования *агрегата* (здесь назвал его *доменной сущностью*) вместе со всей логикой этого процесса. На самом деле, формирование *агрегата* (если это не элементарный *мэппинг*) - обязанность *Service Layer*-а , то есть уровня *API* (или как тут говорил, *Application Layer*-а).

---

P.S. Прошу прощения за путанницу с терминологией.